# Too many parameters in mixins

Tags: pug

Heey, guys! Could someone give me a little help here?
My mixins have been taken too many parameters =/

Example:

```
// file 01:

mixin rm-projects-home__project-item(obj)
  li.rm-projects-home__project-item

    a(class!=[obj.defaultClass, obj.side] href=obj.href alt='Link para a página do projeto')
    div.rm-project-img-hover
      span.rm-project-img-hover__symbol +
    img.rm-projects-home__project-img(src!=obj.imgSrc, alt!=obj.imgAlt)

    div(class!=[obj.projectTitle, obj.textSide])
      p.rm-category.rm-category__projects-home
        span.rm-category__icon.rm-category__icon-projects-home # 
        | #{obj.role}
      h3.rm-projects-home__project-title= obj.projectName


// file 02: 

ul.rm-projects-home__list
  include ../components/projects-home__project-item.pug
  +rm-projects-home__project-item({
    defaultClass: 'rm-projects-home__project-link',
    projectTitle: 'rm-projects-home__title-container',
    href: '#',
    imgSrc: './assets/img/roger-melo-website-thumb.jpg',
    imgAlt: 'Imagem de uma parte do website de Roger Melo',
    projectName: 'My Website',
    role: 'Front-end development'
  })
```

How could I write this better?

Comment: Did you try to create the object and then pass it to the mixin. I'm using objects in mixins in a project and I haven't any problems.

Comment: Roger, can you double check that your indentation is correct? Seems like you'd want everything inside of that `li`.

Comment: @sean I agree, already fix that. Thanks!

Comment: @SergiNadal I'll try this. Do you have any example? Maybe a code in GitHub?

Comment: Why do you think your mixin has too many parameters?  Is there an error?